# How to validate a Regular Expression?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm developing an application in .NET where the user can provide Regular Expressions that are afterwards used to validate input data.

I need a way to know if a regular expression is actually valid for the .net regex engine.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just try to compile the given regex. You can do that by creating the Regex object and passing the pattern to it. Here's a sample code:

```
public static bool IsRegexPatternValid(String pattern)
{
    try
    {
        new Regex(pattern);
        return true;
    }
    catch { }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That's the approach I'm currently using. The issue is that I'm using a try{} catch{} block. I wanted to know if there is a non-exception way of doing this. Thanks nevertheless

Comment: It is just the way Regex class is designed in .NET - to check if a pattern is valid, you need to compile it and see if any exceptions are thrown. I never heard of any other way of doing this.

Comment: Ugh this sucks hard if you're using it as a dynamic filter over a large collection :(