# How to check if an RegEx have the correct syntax?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I want to know if exist any method in `RegEx` class to check if an expression have valid syntax.

I'm not meaning if the regex matches a string or something similar, then the "IsMatch" or "Success" methods does not help me.

To understand me, for example when using the `RegEx.Match` method with this expression it throws an exception because the expression have invalid syntax:

```
"\\\"
```

(without the double quotes)

I've checked the regex class methods but I can't find any like a "tryparser".

Then to check if an expression have valid syntax I'm doing this:

```
Try
    Regex.Match(String.Empty, "\")
    Return True
Catch
    Return False
End Try
```

Just I want to know if I can simplify the code more than that by directly returning a value from a method from `regex` class or converting to boolean the result of a `regex` class method.

> UPDATE:

I create the RegEx in execution time, does not help me external tools.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371408/how-to-validate-a-regular-expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically you can use the constructor of Regex...

```
Private Shared Function IsRegexValid(str As String) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean
    Try
        Dim rx as Regex = New Regex(str)
        result = True
    Catch ex As ArgumentException
        result = False
    End Try
    Return result
End Function
```

or a method that builds a `Regex` object or returns `Nothing`...

```
Private Shared Function TryBuildRegex(str As String) As Regex
    Dim result As Regex
    Try
        result = New Regex(str)
    Catch ex As ArgumentException
        result = Nothing
    End Try
    Return result
End Function
```

Then

```
Dim isvalid As Boolean = IsRegexValid("\")
```

or

```
Dim rx As Regex = TryBuildRegex("\")

If rx IsNot Nothing Then
End If
```

Comment: Thanks but your first function doesnt works trying to use the regex constructor throws an exception 'cause you are trying to use the NEW constructor as first keyword inside a procedure...  but even working you are storing all the new regex objects in memory untill you does not dispose them, but I understand what you are trying to do but basically is a try/catch then just I would know if my original code can be improved more, not extended and allocating objects in mem. thanks again

Comment: @ElektroHacker `Regex` isn't `IDisposable`, so you don't "dispose" them. The Garbage Collector will dispose them when you don't use them anymore. But yes, I create a `Regex` to test if the `Regex` can be created :-)

Comment: If your question was "Is there a `Regex.IsExpressionValid(String)`?" then the response is "no". You have to build the Regex in some way (as the `Regex.Match` does, or as the `new Regex` does) and see if it works.

Comment: Thankyou for the acclaration that is what I would know, and yes I were a little bit conused about the regex object what I would said is I need to execute too many times faster the RegEx try/catch so the GC does not do the work at the moment when is needed. sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are creating your regular expressions dynamically, you could use a tool like [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm) or [The Regulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/).

They are both very good and useful, they will also help you build your expression or analyze an existing one.

Comment: Thanks but is obvious I need code If I ask for C# and VB.NET, not external tools, thanks anyway.

Comment: @ElektroHacker: sorry, then xanatos's answer looks like the way to go.