# create a regex object in C# with text bux input "\q"

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying validate a string based on input(textbox.text) regex pattern.

```
Regex regX = new Regex(TextBox1.Text);
```

It is failing. But

```
Regex regX = new Regex(@"\q");
```

is working fine.

Can you suggest the best way to validate a string based on user regex pattern?

Comment: TextBox1.Text probably doesn't have a valid regex. Use the debugger to inspect the value in TextBox1.Text

Comment: @Adi how is it failing?  What's the error?  Or does it just not work as expected?

Comment: What is the user supposed to enter, a regex pattern or a literal? If it is a literal, just use `==` or `String.Contains()`

Comment: I just wanted to get the input pattern at runtime and validate a string but seems that few regular expressions are not supported in C# (e.g *\q*).

Answer (score 0):

You could validate the pattern before using it like this:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    string pattern = TextBox1.Text;

    if(IsRegexPatternValid(pattern))
    {
        Regex regX = new Regex(pattern);
    }
    else
    {
        // handle invalid patterns here
        return;
    }
}

public static bool IsRegexPatternValid(String pattern)
{
    try
    {
        new Regex(pattern);
        return true;
    }
    catch { }
    return false;
}
```

Source for validating: [How to validate a Regular Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371408/how-to-validate-a-regular-expression)

Your code isnt showing up how you are using the button. But I guess you've bound the `KeyDown` or `TextChanged` handlers. In this case validating would be necessary.

Comment: This is a nice way to skip unsupported regex pattern for the particular language.